# c3p0 - Any issues setting initialPoolSize = minPoolSize = maxPoolSize?

Tags: java, oracle, c3p0, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to root cause some random, intermittent 'freezes' in our service and after discarding several issues, we turned on c3p0 debug level logging for our application and we figured it seems like a c3p0 configuration issue. We use "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production" as our database.

Excerpt from logs shows two lines which are part of the service call. There is no activity for 3 seconds between the two lines which I am unable to attribute to anything in particular.

```
12 Apr 2013 02:25:42,386 [DEBUG] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#8) com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool: Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1507a7] on CHECKIN has SUCCEEDED.

12 Apr 2013 02:25:45,443 [DEBUG] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache: checkinStatement(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.PerConnectionMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 85; checked out: 0; num connections: 5; num keys: 85
```

The c3p0 configuration is as below.

```
acquireIncrement = 2;
acquireRetryAttempts = 0;           # keep retrying forever
acquireRetryDelay = 10000;          # 10 secs.
checkoutTimeout = 1000;             # 1 secs. 
idleConnectionTestPeriod = 60;      # 1 min.
maxConnectionAge = 1800;            # 30 mins.
maxIdleTime = 1800;                 # 30 mins.
maxIdleTimeExcessConnections = 120;
maxPoolSize = 30;
maxStatementsPerConnection = 25;
minPoolSize = 30;
initialPoolSize = 30;
numHelperThreads = 16;  # asynchronous threads
preferredTestQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM dual";
testConnectionOnCheckin = true;
```

I wonder if there is come configuration issue causing the freezing? Also, I want to know if there can be any performance impact (negative) by setting the minPoolSize = maxPoolSize. I was unable to find similar questions / issues that had an answer. I'm not worried about the application startup time, but what happens when a connection has reached its 'age'? I'm trying to understand the c3p0 behavior in dealing with the stale connection.

To give an idea of the load, we get about 300 service calls / minute. CPU / memory usage are all within reasonable levels, nothing particularly of interest there.

Any insights will be appreciated.
Thanks!
-Ameya

Answer (score 0):

1) there should be no problem with minPoolSize = maxPoolSize = initialPoolSize, though it's not a configuration i've tested very much!

2) mostly your config looks pretty good! a few quibbles:

- acquireIncrement of 2 means that, during periods of rising load after some calmer period, roughly 50% of clients will face some delay waiting on Connection acquisition. i'd make acquireIncrement bigger, 3 to 5;
- acquireRetryDelay = 10000 means that any sort of random failure in acquiring a new Connection will cause clients wait()ing on an empty pool to wait 10 seconds if any sort of random glitch causes an acquisition attempt to fail. 10000 is a high setting.
- you are not observing explicit APPARENT DEADLOCK messages, but you are working in a coniguration very liable to them, that is with Oracle + statement caching. there is an issue with some Oracle drivers whereunder an attempt to close() a cached Statement while its parent Connection is in-use (e.g. for a test) causes a freeze, eventually forcing the pool to purge and recreate its helper Threads. You've given yourselves a lot of helper threads, which may be helping to avoid this issue, but under the covers you may be experiencing impairment of performance due to Threads clogged in the Thread pool. c3p0-0.9.2 has a configuration parameter which, if set, i) carefully avoids closing cached PreparedStatements while the parent Connection is in-use and ii) and closes such statements using dedicated Threads. i'd suggest you give this a try. please upgrade, if you have not already, to c3p0-0.9.2.1 and set

  ```
  c3p0.statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads=1
  ```

  (It's unlikely you'll require more than one Thread just to close() Statements, though you can set this to larger values if you'd like. Please see [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads). )

good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! I shall do the requisite changes.